# Converting subquery to Join (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Is it possible to convert these subqueries to join clause?

```
SELECT ods.*,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders) tot_ords,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE order_confirmed = 'yes') yes_ords,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE order_confirmed = 'no') no_ords
FROM orders ods
ORDER BY ods.order_confirmed = 'yes' DESC
```

Comment: Actually in this case we do not need example, but I agree the question is maybe too simple and maybe already answered somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without joins and without subqueries, using analytics:

```
SELECT ods.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER()          tot_ords,
       COUNT(case when order_confirmed = 'yes' then 1 else null end) OVER() yes_ords,
       COUNT(case when order_confirmed = 'no' then 1 else null end) OVER() no_ords
FROM orders ods
ORDER BY ods.order_confirmed = 'yes' DESC
```

Using join:

```
   SELECT ods.*, 
          s.tot_ords,
          s.yes_ords,
          s.no_ords 
     FROM orders ods
          cross join (select 
                             COUNT(*) tot_ords,
                             COUNT(case when order_confirmed = 'yes' then 1 else null end)  yes_ords,        
                             COUNT(case when order_confirmed = 'no' then 1 else null end)  no_ords 
                       from orders
                       ) s
    ORDER BY ods.order_confirmed = 'yes' DESC
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work ;( I see syntax error (SQL Error 1064)

Comment: @Artem Added answer with join. fixed

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use conditional aggregation,

```
    select *, Count(*) over() tot_ords,
        Sum(case when order_confirmed ='yes' then 1 else 0 end) over() yes_ords,
        Sum(case when order_confirmed ='no' then 1 else 0 end) over() no_ords
    from orders
  from orders ods
  order by ods.order_confirmed = 'yes' DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, but what about JOIN clause?

Comment: For MySQL specifically, this is unnecessarily verbose

Comment: @Artem Join? You are only selecting from one table, sorry you've lost me.you can't join anything without a correlation.

Comment: In fact I didn't even spot your select *, so apologies leftjoin's query is more appropriate, why you would want to make it unecessarily more resource-intensive is a mystery, selecting from a single table there is no need to join anything with aggregate functions; sample data and required output would have helped :-))

Comment: I'm afraid that if I use subqueries instead of joins, then with a significant increase in the size of the table, the overall performance will dramatically decrease

Comment: @Artem Sorry I'm not following your logic on that one - the answer you accepted is fine based on what you have in your example query. You want to avoid unecessary joins and subqueries at all costs - why read the same table more than once if you don't have to? Using aggregate and `over()` clause gets you your counts at no additional cost - that's the only solution you want.